# subtract a common background from a set of multiple images

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have to remove background (16 bit tiff image) from series of images ( number of images = 250, also 16 bit tiff) as shown in actual figure [main sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n0q5.png) (jpg of the main image is uploded) . I have written the following code to do the same, but the subtraction part is not working properly. The resulting image has counts of 5000 at the corners (extremally bright pixels) as shown in figure subtracted [subtracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s10G.jpg) (jpg of the resulting image is uploaded). Please let me know where the problem is in this code.

```
#read image series 
S01=[i for i in glob.glob("C:/Users/experiment 2/S01/*.tif")] #16 bit tiff main image
S02=[i for i in glob.glob("C:/Users/experiment 2/S02/*.tif")] #16 bit tiff background image

#average the background 
bg=np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in S02])
bg_avg=np.array(np.mean(bg,axis=(0)),dtype=np.uint16)
bg_out=Image.fromarray(bg_avg) #image to plot using imshow

#remove background image from each of the main image
main=np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in S01]) #(has maximum of 1200)
main_sub=np.subtract(main,bg_avg) # i am not sure if this line in the code is actually subtracting background from the series of main image
main_avg=np.array(np.mean(main_sub,axis=(0)),dtype=np.uint16) 
main_out=Image.fromarray(flame_avg) #(has maximum of 5000)

Plt.figure
subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(main_out)
subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(bg_out)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide actual, individual images that folks can work with rather than pictures/screengrabs of images with axes and joined together. Thank you. You may need Dropbox or Google Drive for 16-bit TIFFs.

Comment: you're working with **unsigned ints** when you should work with **signed ints**. negative differences will wrap around because you are working with unsigned ints. -- use `.astype(np.int16)` (or dtype=np.int16) if your values are never above 32767, otherwise use int32