# convert multidimensional nd array from uint16 to int16

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, tiff, grayscale, uint16

When I read an 16 bit tiff (gray scale image having two dimension) image using scipy, and check its dtype using `image.dtype` I get uint16 (Uint16 is unassigned 16 bit integer). I want **int16** to work further in my code. Could you please give a quick method to convert from **uint16** type nd array **int16** nd array

Comment: You can use `image.astype(np.int16) ` to change the data type

Comment: "unassigned"? No, this does not mean unassigned, it means unsigned.

Comment: what do u expect for values above 2^15 to become? clipped to 2^15? turn to negative?
for example: the original pixel is (2^16-1). what do u expect its new value in the int16 type?

Comment: This was already explained to you by Christoph here https://stackoverflow.com/q/72437015/2836621 and demonstrated by me here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73082666/2836621